# TypeError: 'Reference' object is not iterable

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

anyone can help me?

I want to retrieve data from the **Firebase Realtime Database**

my **main.py**:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate ("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app (cred, {"databaseURL": "https://myDatabase.firebaseio.com/"})

ref = db.reference ("user")

for u in ref:
     print (ref.get())
```

and I get an error message like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
     for u in ref:
TypeError: 'Reference' object is not iterable
```

I am just learning Firebase by using Python.
I hope you can help, thank you :)

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to load the data at `ref`. In that case you should just use `print (ref.get())`, without the loop around it (which is precisely what the message is complaining about).

Comment: I use looping because I want to release data one by one from ```user```. what do you think I should do? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: To know what users there are, you first need to have the data. So the loop should happen **after** you `get()` the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, you are trying to print the data of each user under the `/user` key in your database. The code `db.reference("user")` returns an object that refers to a location on your database and doesn't hold any data. To get a list of each user, you would use a variation of the following code:

```py
ref = db.reference("user")

data = ref.get() # get data from db

for u in data # iterate children of data
   print(u)
```

Comment: yeah now there are no errors, I'm very grateful :) @samthecodingman

Answer (score 2):

This answer is to help you debug such errors in future by yourself. :)
The error is telling you that you have a "TypeError", the first thing you should probably do is check the type of ref by doing `print(type(ref))`, is that an iterable? Most likely no, which is why you get the error. The next step should be checking either the docs online or locally the functions provided by `ref`. You could do this by starting a new shell, typing all the commands till before the for loop and the `dir(ref)`. You will see a wide range of functions there, which one seems most legit of the names that would "get" you the data? `get` of course. There you go. :)

Comment: wow very good advice I will run the advice from you, thank you very much :) @unixia